# Unable to pull docker image for pixel streaming on Linux server

Tags: docker, unreal-engine4

I am unable to pull docker image for pixel streaming on Linux server.

```
[root@server~]# docker pull ghcr.io/epicgames/pixel-streaming-signalling-server:4.27.2
Error response from daemon: unauthorized
```

When I tried docker login it returns "Login Succeeded", but I am still unable to download the image.

```
[root@server~]# echo $CR_PAT | docker login ghcr.io -u <username> --password-stdin
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
Login Succeeded
```

Answer (score 1):

After 2 days of research, I found out that the GitHub personal access token did not have sufficient rights to download the image. After modifying these rights, I was able to download this image.

Comment: Can you tell us how did you modify rights, that worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

For people who are still looking for details of the solution to this issue.

If you're trying to pull docker images from the "ghcr.io/epicgames" GitHub Container Registry, you'll need to authenticate using a GitHub Personal Access Token (PAT).

Here's how to do it:

1. Make sure your GitHub PAT has not expired. If needed, update it at https://github.com/settings/tokens.
2. In the "Select scopes" section of your token, make sure that the "read:packages" scope is checked. You can review this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icRaF.png).
3. Log in to the GitHub Container Registry using your PAT:

`docker login ghcr.io --username=YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME --password=YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN`

Once you've completed these steps, you should be able to pull the image from the registry.

For more information, you can refer to the [official Unreal Engine documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/quick-start-guide-for-using-container-images-in-unreal-engine/) on using container images.

I hope this information helps. Happy coding!